# passing dynamic column name to a temp table not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have this `Sql` puzzle i'm using Sql server 2005

the following query works fine

```
 DECLARE @query VARCHAR(200)
 DECLARE @colname varchar(50) 
     CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , value VARCHAR(50))
       INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('first')
       SET @colname = 'myCol'
       SET @query = 'SELECT value AS' + @colname + ' FROM #temp'
        EXEC(@query)
     DROP TABLE #temp
```

**BUT**

if i do this

```
  SET @colname = (SELECT value FROM tablename WHERE id = 12) --valid selection
```

or

```
  SELECT @colname = value FROM tablename WHERE id = 12 --valid selection
```

I don't get any result , i get a message saying :

```
  (1 row(s) affected)
```

AND ERROR Message:

```
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
  Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

Any body knows what is going on with this thing Thanks

Comment: What does `SELECT value FROM tablename WHERE id = 12` return? My guess is nothing at all or `NULL` so `@colname` ends up as `NULL` and concatenating `NULL` yields `NULL` and nothing is executed. The `(1 row(s) affected)` comes from the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Have you added `PRINT @query` to see what you're actually executing?

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right it return nothing see update

Comment: Your second error message indicates that you need to use `SELECT @colname = quotename(value) FROM tablename WHERE id = 12`. Probably you are setting `@colname` to a value such as `1` which is not a valid un delimited identifier.

Comment: i've tried your code (change the tablename to #temp) and it's doesn't give me the error

Comment: @IswantoSan it should though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments you need to guard against the value being `NULL` because nothing was assigned or the column name being an invalid SQL Server identifier.

You can do the former by checking `@@ROWCOUNT` after the assignment and the second by using `QUOTENAME`

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @colname VARCHAR(50)

CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     ID    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     value VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES      ('first')

SELECT @colname = QUOTENAME(value)
FROM   tablename
WHERE  id = 12

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1
  BEGIN
      RAISERROR('Unexpected rowcount',16,1)

      RETURN
  END

SET @query = 'SELECT value AS ' + @colname + ' FROM #temp'

EXEC(@query)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko - Thanks. The space after `AS` isn't actually required as the alias is delimited but have added it anyway. `SELECT 1 AS[2]` works fine.

Comment: can you tell me why did i need QUOTENAME()

Comment: @MinaGabriel - This is best practice anyway to avoid possible SQL injection issues but `1` is not a valid un delimited SQL identifier and needs to be quoted. `SELECT 'Foo' AS 1` gives a syntax error but `SELECT 'Foo' AS [1]` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#temp` table has identity column and your query only insert to the `#temp` table once..
So you only have `ID = 1`.
`ID = 12` is not exists.

This query will be give the result.

```
 DECLARE @query VARCHAR(200)
 DECLARE @colname varchar(50) 
 CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , value VARCHAR(50))
       INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('first')
       SELECT @colname = value FROM #temp WHERE id = 1
       SET @query = 'SELECT value AS' + @colname + ' FROM #temp'
        EXEC(@query)
 DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: The select is against a different table.